# Force Facebook OG Image Consistency

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

Facebook OG Image stuff is a nightmare. How do you tackle keeping images consistently appearing on Facebook right? I am currently struggling to get a default image setup for the forum of a website. The forum is in phpBB. I have added this code to the header.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fyxtrpg.com/wp-content/gallery/assets/fyxt-rpg-forum-default-facebook-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="484">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="252">
```

The image is set to the exact size it is supposed to be. I even tell Facebook that. But it still chops off both ends.

I also get an error saying it can't download the image or it is too small. it is not to small, exceeding the 200px min. It is also listed IN the debugger and showing that Facebook can indeed download it just fine.

My URL: https://fyxtrpg.com/fyxt-forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=128

Facebook Debug Info

```
Time Scraped    2 seconds ago
Response Code   206
Fetched URL https://fyxtrpg.com/fyxt-forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=128
Canonical URL   https://fyxtrpg.com/fyxt-forum/index.php
Notice
Warnings That Should Be Fixed
og:image could not be downloaded or is too small    og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'https://fyxtrpg.com/wp-content/gallery/assets/fyxt-rpg-public-beta-logo.jpg' will be used instead.
To find the object, these are the redirects we had to follow
original    https://fyxtrpg.com/fyxt-forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=128
og:url  https://fyxtrpg.com/fyxt-forum/index.php
The following will be treated as a redirect by the crawler:
A HTTP redirect
A <link rel="canonical" href=".." /> tag
A <meta property="og:url" content=".." /> tag
The final URL, which we tried to extract metadata from is highlighted in bold
These are the raw tags that we found
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="https://fyxtrpg.com/fyxt-forum/index.php" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="Fyxt RPG Forums" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="The free to play Fyxt RPG system offers RPG players a fun, fast, and flexible RPG experience. Play any genre, setting, or character for free with Fyxt RPG!" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="https://fyxtrpg.com/wp-content/gallery/assets/fyxt-rpg-forum-default-facebook-image.jpg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:width" content="484" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image:height" content="252" />
Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties
og:url  https://fyxtrpg.com/fyxt-forum/index.php
og:type website
og:title    Fyxt RPG Forums
og:image    
og:description  The free to play Fyxt RPG system offers RPG players a fun, fast, and flexible RPG experience. Play any genre, setting, or character for free with Fyxt RPG!
og:updated_time 1417807331
```

As you can see the debugger says it can't find it then shows me all the data it actually DID find.

When I post the image is cropped, but if I delete that and manually upload it fits fine. That is not acceptable, I need know that anyone sharing something from the website is going to have a decent image appear along with it. Not one that is chopped or distorted.

How do I fix this so Facebook sees the image AND displays it correctly, consistently?

Is there a process of method that someone can suggest to insure that all links to the website will be X size photo/thumbnail? It is really frustrating as it seems that sometimes Facebook uses a portrait, other times a landscape, other times a square. I have even noticed it using different methods to post the same picture. This makes it very difficult to make sure the images look good on Facebook.

Thank you for your advice and help!

More info added... I have also sent in numerous Facebook bug reports because this stuff needs to be fixed.

I have also found that Facebook is not being consistent between creating and posting. This includes resolution, ratio, and a couple other things. Here is one mess I found on ONE attempted post.

If anyone has any suggestions I am eager to hear how to actually work WITH Facebook and their API and not against it...

[image: Facebooks Many Image Errors]

Comment: Having similar issues,  However I'm using Drupal CMS.  My images are cropped to  600x315 as specified by Facebook, but the FB Debugger gives me the same warning about the og:image not being able to be downloaded or being too small.  And then down in the preview area, sometimes it does use the correct image, other times it does not.  Totally useless debug information. I feel your pain  :-/

Comment: Good question, shame nobody answered it! Struggling with the same things...

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this over the last few days. It seems that Facebook only takes the OG tags as suggestions. I discovered that if your image is closer to a square, and it finds a large enough image that is closer to it's ideal aspect ratio, then it will use that one.

Also, even though they say the minimum is 600px X 315px, they really do prefer images above 1200px X 630px.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images